# using custom date extracted from logs in timestamp

Tags: kibana, logstash-grok

I have date in my log as `09 Jul 2019`. I want the timestamp date which comes by default in Kibana to use this date.

I have defined the custom pattern for extracting the date as `AV_DATE %{MONTHDAY} %{MONTH} %{YEAR}`
.
How do I map this date to `@timestamp` field?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using logstash try the following:

```
date {
            match => ["AV_DATE", "ISO8601"]
        }
```

or try the following:

```
date {
    match => ["AV_DATE", "ISO8601"]
    target => "@timestamp"
}
```